# Эмуляция нажатия клавиатуры (для набора текста)

Tags: c++, клавиатура

Всех приветствую. Есть, к примеру, такой текст:

string text_for_write = "hello, world";

Как можно эмулировать нажатия на все эти клавиши?

Текст может быть рандомным

P.S OC - windows, конкретно win 10

Comment: Уточните целевую ОС

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: goldstar_labs, готово